# Complexity of retrieval of newest datetime entry in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to:

```
select 
       max_date = max( dates)
from some_table t
```

where dates is `datetime` in form of

`2014-10-29 23:34:11`

and is primary key, so is indexed.

What is the retrieval complexity for big databases?

Comment: I guess it might be dependent on the backing index structure, but according to [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_storage_structures) _most databases use indexes on the primary keys, resulting in retrieval times of O(log n) or O(1) for keys that are the same as the database row offsets within the storage system._ which seems reasonable. My knowledge of MySQL internals is too limited to say for certain though, hence the comment and not answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `date` column is primary key it will be unique and indexed. So, it should be fine.
Per MySQL documentation, if you use `WHERE` clause along with the `MAX()` function then the query will be optimized and will be faster.

In your case, you are just trying to get the maximum date, you can as well use `OEDER BY` with `LIMIT` like below which will take advantage of index on `dates` column and will be faster

```
select `dates`
from some_table
order by `dates` desc 
limit 1;
```